# What's causing xd_arbiter.php to flood my access log?

Tags: facebook

AWS alarm watch triggered and when I look into my access log, this is what goes on for miles and miles:

```
14.140.146.5 - - [27/Jul/2012:10:30:18 -0400] "GET /2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/?fb_xd_fragment HTTP/1.1" 200 65182 "http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=9" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
14.140.146.5 - - [27/Jul/2012:10:30:20 -0400] "GET /2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/?fb_xd_fragment HTTP/1.1" 200 65182 "http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=9" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
14.140.146.5 - - [27/Jul/2012:10:30:20 -0400] "GET /2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/?fb_xd_fragment HTTP/1.1" 200 65182 "http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=9" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
14.140.146.5 - - [27/Jul/2012:10:30:22 -0400] "GET /2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/?fb_xd_fragment HTTP/1.1" 200 65182 "http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=9" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
14.140.146.5 - - [27/Jul/2012:10:30:22 -0400] "GET /2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/?fb_xd_fragment HTTP/1.1" 200 65182 "http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=9" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
14.140.146.5 - - [27/Jul/2012:10:30:24 -0400] "GET /2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/?fb_xd_fragment HTTP/1.1" 200 65182 "http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=9" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
14.140.146.5 - - [27/Jul/2012:10:30:24 -0400] "GET /2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/?fb_xd_fragment HTTP/1.1" 200 65182 "http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=9" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
...
```

Any idea what's causing Facebook to slam my server like this?

Comment: do you have a like button? if so, does it happen if you remove it?

Comment: I did have a Like button, but note how all requests come from the same IP. Commenting out the button did not help. Now the offending IP is a DROP in my iptables for a while...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is the hash based Cross-Domain messaging kicking in, something that only happens in older browsers that don't support postMessage, and which does not have Flash installed (From the log you can see that this is IE6).

The good thing is that you can avoid these requests from ever hitting your server by setting up, and passing in the path to the `channelUrl` when performing `FB.init`.

[This blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/530/) gives you some insights into how to do this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. After looking over Analytics data I concluded there is little value in keeping the Like button so I removed it. But the FB blog post is still very good resource, ty.